# How to add running total to query with left join to calendar table in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server-2012

How do I add a column with running total to the following query which has already a left join on a calendar table? Preferably the solution should have good performance. Target is SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT 
    calendar.year, calendar.month,
    COUNT(users.ID) AS total_users
FROM 
    core_Calendar AS calendar
LEFT JOIN 
    users_Users AS users ON CONVERT(DATE, calendar.date) = CONVERT(DATE, users.CreatedAt)
WHERE 
    calendar.year >= 2012
    AND calendar.year <= Year({ts '2016-01-06 19:23:27'})
GROUP BY 
    calendar.year, calendar.month
ORDER BY 
    calendar.year, calendar.month
```

Comment: Basically you would need to use ROW_NUMBER() partition function. There is something wrong with query as the MONTH(calendar.date) is not present in SELECT and it should be throwing error. In terms of performance, when you put functions ins filter clause, they are non SARGABLE meaning it will have a poor execution plan and it will result in slow output.

Comment: I removed MONTH(calendar.date). It's superfluous, but no error was thrown.

Answer (score 0):

When you say running total, I understand you are referring to count of users.
If so, try this query -

```
SELECT 
    calendar.year, calendar.month,
    SUM(isnull(users.ID),0) OVER PARTITION BY(calendar.year,calendar.month) AS total_users
FROM 
    core_Calendar AS calendar
LEFT JOIN 
    users_Users AS users ON CONVERT(DATE, calendar.date) = CONVERT(DATE, users.CreatedAt)
WHERE 
    calendar.year >= 2012
    AND calendar.year <= Year({ts '2016-01-06 19:23:27'})
GROUP BY 
    calendar.year, calendar.month
ORDER BY 
    calendar.year, calendar.month
```